# Optimize code block for LINQ and non LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-datatable

I have 2 code block to do same a work and have same target create some thing, but I don't know which block is the best (I mean LINQ or non-LINQ)?

First of all, can anyone tell me how to optimize on the code blocks?  And the lastly, help me find the best style between LINQ and non-LINQ:

First block is:

```
if (tblone.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            tblone.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => (string)x["id"] == "true").ToList()
                .ForEach(x => tbltwo.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(y => y["category"] == x["cate"]).ToList().ForEach(
                    z =>
                    {
                        tblthree.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                          .ToList<DataRow>()
                                          .ForEach(k => datatemp.Rows.Add(k["m"].ToString()));
                        tblfour.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                            .ToList<DataRow>()
                            .ForEach(k => datatemp.Rows.Add(k["m"].ToString()));
                    }));
        }
```

Second block is:

```
if (tblone.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var idx = 0; idx < tblone.Rows.Count; idx++)
            {
                if (bool.Parse(tblone.Rows[idx]["subset"].ToString()))
                {
                    for (var kdx = 0; kdx < tbltwo.Rows.Count; kdx++)
                    {
                        if (tbltwo.Rows[kdx]["category"].ToString() == tblone.Rows[idx]["cate"].ToString())
                        {
                            for (var zdx = 0; zdx < tblthree.Rows.Count; zdx++)
                                datatemp.Rows.Add(tblthree.Rows[zdx]["m"].ToString());
                            for (var zdx = 0; zdx < tblfour.Rows.Count; zdx++)
                                datatemp.Rows.Add(tblfour.Rows[zdx]["m"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `ForEach()` is not LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

First - if you are working with DataTables, then you can use [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx), which has nice extension methods to get field values.

Now let's review logic of your code. You are not using any data from `tblone` and `tbltwo` in your result. Actually you only finding joined categories between these two tables, and for each matched rows pair you are adding all `m` values from `tblthree` and `tblfour` to result. I find this logic pretty strange. Maybe you are expecting only single match here. Then you will need boolean result (match found or not). But basically you need *count of joined rows*:

```
var matchedCategoriesCount = 
            (from one in tblone.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<bool>("id"))
             join two in tbltwo.AsEnumerable()
                on one.Field<string>("cate") equals two.Field<string>("category")
             select one).Count();
```

Same with lambda syntax if you find it more readable:

```
var matchedCategoriesCount = 
            tblone.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<bool>("id"))
                  .Join(tbltwo.AsEnumerable(),
                        one => one.Field<string>("cate"),
                        two => two.Field<string>("category"),
                        (one, two) => one)
                  .Count();
```

Then you can select `m` values from `tblthree` and `tblfour` N times and create new `DataTable`:

```
// if (matchedCategoriesCount > 0)
var values = tblthree.AsEnumerable().Concat(tblfour.AsEnumerable())
                     .Select(r => r.Field<string>("m")))
                     .ToArray();
```

You can even use simple loop here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matchedCategoriesCount; i++)
   foreach(var value in values)
       datatemp.Rows.Add(value);
```

And last - don't use variable names like `tblone`, `tbltwo`, `tblthree` etc. These names does not explain what data these variables hold. Use names from domain of your application.

Comment: Thank you so much,but AsEnumerable().Select(something) . I can't find Select() method after AsEnumerable().

Comment: And next problem is Join. My code mind that : find and loop each rows in table one and find the id field is true. After that, find in table two match value with category field and cate. So, Join is okie , why you suggested that only count ()?? I want to loop each rows in match condition ! Please explain more detail for me .

Comment: I found  Linq to DataSet , But I can't find the namespace ,  please tell me the namespace :)

Comment: @user51150 you can find extensions in same namespaces as classes which they are extent - `System.Data`. Make sure you have link to *System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll*

Comment: Oh, I totally understand, You are right , count() and loop value. And I find the namespace of LINQ to DataSet. I vote for you !